# Dynamic query for stored procedure

Tags: mysql, pivot

I need query of looping in stored procedure for table like this:

Table Matrix Report

```
| Nama  | Motor   |
|-------|---------|
| Abdul | Vario   |
| Abdul | Beat    |
| Mei   | Supra   |
| Leli  | Supra   |
| Budi  | Megapro |
| Ali   | CB150   |
```

Output :

```
| Nama   | Vario | Beat | Supra | Megapro | CB150 |
|--------|-------|------|-------|---------|-------|
| Abdul  | 1     | 1    | 0     | 0       | 0     |
| Mei    | 0     | 0    | 1     | 0       | 0     |
| Leli   | 0     | 0    | 1     | 0       | 0     |
| Budi   | 0     | 0    | 0     | 1       | 0     |
| Ali    | 0     | 0    | 0     | 0       | 1     |
```

I need dynamic query because if I added new data, they automatically sum up.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need a dynamic query, you need a pivot query:

```
SELECT Nama,
SUM(CASE WHEN Motor = 'Vario' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Vario,
SUM(CASE WHEN Motor = 'Beat' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Beat,
SUM(CASE WHEN Motor = 'Supra' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Supra,
SUM(CASE WHEN Motor = 'Megapro' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Megapro
SUM(CASE WHEN Motor = 'CB150' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CB150
FROM MatrixReport
GROUP BY Nama;
```

This query will automatically sum up whether new rows are added or not.

This is a SQL query, not an SP. You need to learn more about how to create a stored procedure. Take a look at these Stack Overflow Q & As to help you in creating your first SP:

- [Beginners' guide to stored procedures with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278392/beginners-guide-to-stored-procedures-with-mysql)
- [Creating a Procedure MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755003/creating-a-procedure-mysql)
- [MySQL create stored procedure syntax with delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786240/mysql-create-stored-procedure-syntax-with-delimiter)

You should also learn more about `GROUP_CONCAT` function in MySQL:

- [Aggregate (`GROUP BY`) Function Descriptions - `GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)
- [How to use GROUP_CONCAT in a CONCAT in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql)